# Why are my values multiplying when I apply Month/Year to my values?

Tags: tableau-api

When I apply Month/Year to Cases or Deaths from my data, the values explode. For Cases it goes from approximately 48 million to over 1 billion, and for Deaths it goes from about 700 thousand to over 22 million. However, when I try the same thing with Initial Claims or the Stringency Index, my values remain correct. I'm trying to find the month over month percentage change by the way. And I'm using the Date column. I only select 2020 and 2021 in the filter for Year.

What I'm asking about is Sheet 21.

Link to workbook: https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/nilajah.rivers/viz/CoronaVirusProject_16323687296770/Sheet21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the data points are daily *cumulative* deaths. If you change the date aggregation to anything other than days, Tableau will default to *summing* the numbers for all the days in the month. This will give the wrong result, obviously.

If you want to show the correct total deaths or cases regardless of the time aggregation (months, days, weeks etc.) then you could use the `New Case` or `New Death` numbers plus a running sum table calculation. This will always give the correct total for the time period.

Table calculations will also allow automatic calculation of the period to period % change from the same data fields.

This is a common problem when working with datasets that offer pre-calculated aggregations. Tableau doesn't need that as it can dynamically calculate the aggregation of a field over any given time period but it is easy to forget which field has pre-aggregated data and which has raw data. Pre-aggregated fields *assume* a particular time period and can't be used for different time periods without disentangling that assumption (which is unnecessary if you also have the raw data (in this case daily new deaths/cases).

Comment: This worked @matt_black. Thanks a lot for your help.